# Prove that every sequence $a_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n\neq 0$, that converges to $0$ satisfies the following:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, radicals, fractions

Prove that every sequence $a_n$,  $n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n\neq 0$, that converges to 0 (The german word for this kind of sequence is "Nullfolge", I don't know how to translate this) satisfies the following:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n}-1}{a_n}=\frac{1}{2}$

If the sequence is "positive", $a_n$ seems to be greater than$ \sqrt{1+a_n}-1$ because $\sqrt{1+a_n}$ is bigger than 1, but smaller than $1+a_n$, and subtracting 1 doesn't really change something, but I don't see if this could help me ???

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's equivalent to find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 + x} - 1 }{x}$  .

Comment: Use S.H.W's hint and l'hopital rule.

Comment: A "null sequence" could be what Germans call Nullfolge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}$ is a continuous function in $x=0$, we obtain:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+a_n}-1}{a_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{1+a_n}-1)(\sqrt{1+a_n}+1)}{a_n(\sqrt{1+a_n}+1)}=$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n(\sqrt{1+a_n}+1)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a_n}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems so obvious to me now that I'm a bit ashamed for having asked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Poujh You are welcome!